# E-mail Content of SharePoint 2013 Blog

Tags: sharepoint-online, blog, outlook

I am trying to do a very simple task, which is to email the content of my Blog post. I don't want the content formatting to change at all. There is an "Email link", but I don't need to email the link. I need to email the content of the Blog in the body of the Email.

This should not be a difficult objective and maybe I am over looking a setting?

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Can you explain how are you planning to send email? A timer job or a workflow or custom webpart etc?

Comment: I don't have a workflow attached. It's just a simple blog and I have a content query displaying 3 most recent posts. Ideally I wish there were a button, like the "email link". Does it not have that functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box what you are looking is not available. The reason being, SharePoint don't want to send the actual content in email. Rather it want users to login to the site and collaborate.

You need to custom code to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Bummer... Have any links that have information on that?

Comment: You can look in google. Here are couple of points you can search. (1) Reading a blogpost html data (2) Sending email in SharePoint Online

Comment: I did see where you could post to the blog via email.... When I put the web address to the list in the "To" or "CC" text field it says "Outlook doesn't recognzie this"? Any way around that? If I can get around that I can just send it to the people I am wanting to send post to and to the blog and would solve the issue

Comment: Sorry didn't understand what you are saying. You mean Outllook has an option to sent the blogpost as an email?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Add-content-to-sites-by-sending-email-b989a9f3-14de-4e59-9faf-b843ec40cabb

Comment: Look at the last point

Comment: Its the other way around. It says if a user want to make a new blog post he/she can do that by sending an email to the SharePoint site. For this first you should configure incoming email settings etc. I believe this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah I understand that it is the opposite, but I could say "To: everyone" "Cc: Blog". Is the incoming email settings in SharePoint?